# How to get the last digit of a number without using modulus(%) operator?

Tags: math, modulus

> If we are told that we can't use modulus operator then how can we take
>   out the last digit of a number.

**e.g.**
`N=2345,` we should get 5.

Try to provide a generic solution.

**What I found:**

```
N- N/ 10 * 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you provided will work.

Generally speaking, for Integers >= 0 this will always be true

A % B = A - [A/B] * B, where [x] denotes greatest integer <= x

Comment: Will not work with doubles though. Remember to convert to int first. But %10 will

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/e51mg205/

```
number = 2345;
arr = (""+number).split('');
console.log(arr[arr.length-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

By casting.
but this require some checks before.

simple example:

```
int num = 15;
double d = num/10; //d = 1.5
num = num/10;  //num = 1;
int lastNumber = (d - (double)num) * 10;
```